# Div not being found when Ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django template that looks like this:

**page.html**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
   <div class="example">
      ..some..content..
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Inside `base.html` contains a wrapper div that wraps everything up.

I'm trying to retrieve this page like so in Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/page/',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log($(data).find(".wrapper"));
    }
});
```

However, the log says that `.wrapper` does not exist for some reason, even though if I do `console.log(data);` it shows the wrapper and all the HTML. Is it because the tag hasn't loaded yet? If so, how can I make it show?

Comment: have you try with `complete: function(data) {}` ?

Comment: @SancaKembang yes, but it still doesn't show the wrapper